# Adding A Moodle Project to Source Control

Tags: php, github, deployment, moodle

I'm not a php nor moodle developer.  I worked as a python developer for many years and now work as a devops eng.

One of my clients uses the moodle framework for their site with no source control.  I've spoken with their lead developer and he insists there's no way to have a moodle repo without the entire directory structure in the repository, that is all the `auth`, `admin`, `backup`, `badges`, etc directories, since many files in those directories have been touched by their development team

I did a file count and it's over 50K files, which is insane for a code repo.

Has anyone managed to solve this problem for a moodle site before?  Specifically a clean CI process using source control?

Answer (score 2):

I have been through a similar process on several occasions. Your best bet is to clone a clean copy of Moodle from the github repo. Then look at the version.php file on the client site to identify the exact version they are using. Next checkout that same version in the clean copy (use gitk to search for that version number). Finally copy across the code from the client site and then the standard git commands should allow you to audit what has changed and commit it in sensible steps.

Once cleaned up, keep all the changes in a branch.

Comment: this sounds like a good approach.  I have to test it first thought before accepting the answer.  also how does the team continue to do development? is there anyway I can only keep the changed files in the repo? then ask them to add in newly changed field?

Comment: New dev should go on dev branch then merge in. I would advise starting a new main branch for each Moodle release  (e.g. 2.9.1 to 2.9.2) and use rebase to put the local changes back on top of the latest release.